# Querying a date and doing minus todays date, sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So currently i am trying to do a function that queries my db and send an email if the user didnt emit any data for 14 days. Right now i am stuck and i am getting this type of error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'result'
i am not sure if it has something to do with my query. Please help.

Here is the function

```
    datahoje=datetime.utcnow()
    ultimadata=Dado.query.order_by(Dado.user_id == user).filter(extract('year',Dado.DataDeInsercao),extract('month',Dado.DataDeInsercao),extract('day',Dado.DataDeInsercao)).first()
    diff= datahoje-ultimadata
    if diff >=14:
        msg = Message('Falta de dados',sender='ivgnoreply@gmail.com', recipients= [dueduser])
        msg.body =   'Isso e um email para vc parar de ser vagabundo'
        mail.send(msg)
```

Here is my db classes just for understanding

```
class UsuarioDB(db.Model,UserMixin):
__tablename__= "UsuarioDB"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
UsernameDB = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
EmailDB = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)    
PasswordDB = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)


class Dado(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
DataDeInsercao = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('UsuarioDB.id'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: For your query try calling `.scalar()` instead of `.first()`

Comment: Well at least now i know it is returning multiple rows thank u, but still i need to query two columns the user id to filter by and the  dateofinsertion one, how would i make it select only the first value? Of dateofinsertion

Comment: [.scalar()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar) should only return the first column of the first row. In this case I would expect it to return a `datetime.date`.

Comment: So does `lastsentdate= db.session.query(func.date(Dado.DataDeInsercao)).filter_by(user_id= user).order_by(Dado.id.desc()).scalar()` return a single value?

Comment: No still multiples, the thing is i want to extract the year month day time from the queried data, together something i am having problems with. But i think i am close with this query

Comment: ultimadata=Dado.query.order_by(Dado.user_id == user).filter(extract('year',Dado.DataDeInsercao),extract('month',Dado.DataDeInsercao),extract('day',Dado.DataDeInsercao)).first()

Comment: yup that failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229835/discussion-between-ingl0r1am0r1-and-gord-thompson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i managed to do it for those who may need it in the future here it is a function that sends and email automatically whenever the user doesnt insert anything into ur database after a certain period of time. Made in flask and sqlalchemy.
Function

```
def enviar_email_checkup():
users= ['1','2']
for user in users:
    ultimadata=db.session.query(Dado.DataDeInsercao).filter_by(user_id = user).order_by(Dado.DataDeInsercao.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
    dueduser=db.session.query(UsuarioDB.EmailDB,UsuarioDB.id).filter_by(id = user).order_by(UsuarioDB.id.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
    datahoje=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    diff= datahoje-ultimadata
    if diff.days >= 2:
        msg = Message('Falta de dados',sender='ivgnoreply@gmail.com', recipients= [dueduser])
        msg.body =   'Isso e um email para vc parar de ser vagabundo'
        mail.send(msg)
    else:
        break
```